# Where to find a pretrained doc2vec model on Wikipedia or large article dataset like Google news?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

Am struggling with training wikipedia dump on doc2vec model, not experienced in setting up a server as a local machine is out of question due to the ram it requires to do the training. I couldnt find a pre trained model except outdated copies for python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any publicly-available standard gensim `Doc2Vec` models trained on Wikipedia.